# iPhone 7+ text message with no contact or text but location is on?

Tags: messages, privacy, iphone

Browsing through my **Messages** on my iPhone 7+, I recently found a thread with no name, no number, and no message body. However when I click the **ⓘ** in the top right corner, I get the options to **Send My Current Location** and **Stop Sharing My Location**.

I do not currently have my location shared with anyone, and seeing **Stop Sharing My Location** is a little scary.

Has this happened to anyone? What would cause this? Thanks for the help!

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This could be a corrupted **Messages** database. If you have your texts set to expire after a certain amount of time (under **Settings** → **Messages** → **Keep Messages**), your message threads would normally get emptied out, although the number would remain at the top.

You can find out for certain whether you’re sharing your location with anybody by going into **Settings** → **Personal Profile** (at the very top) → **iCloud** → **Share My Location**. If the list there is empty you should be fine, though you might still want to **Stop Sharing My Location** to see if an error/change occurs.

The **Personal Profile** submenu exists in iOS 10.3 and later. Otherwise just directly scroll down to **iCloud** after opening **Settings**.